# maximum post size in php using codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I post 6 array with each count 192 using Ajax to controller. The 192 array count is sent to controller. I see using firebug. But Only first 69 array count is get in controller.  But it is work well in localhost. Not work in live.

Comment: Increase max_execution_time,time_limit in php.ini file.

Comment: @TBI In what measurement I should set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the values in php.ini file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); //display the errors

ini_set('max_execution_time', 18000);
```

Comment: I place ini_set('max_execution_time', 18000); in controller file but same issue occure.

Comment: Issue means only 69 count array is reached in controller file.

Comment: Try to increase post_max_size too. 
set_time_limit(-1);
ini_set('post_max_size','200M');

Answer (score 4):

Php has a default limit of 1000 variables in post your post data might be having more than that number of variable please increase the max_input_vars to a larger number in .htaccess or php.ini file